# Arrow operator VS passing the argument in function: what is the difference?

Tags: angular, typescript

//component.ts
What is the difference in putting `i` as arrow operator or putting `i` within a function.

```
this.service.getuser().subscribe(i => {
    this.myuserList = i;
});
```

// As shown below, the below code the data data is not painted in html page

```
this.service.getUserList().subscribe(function(i : any){
    this.myuserList = i;
});
```

// Also putting the html code for reference

```
//component.html 
<tr *ngFor = 'let p of myuserList'>
<td>{{p.username}}</td>
<td>{{p.address.suite}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `function` (ES5 syntax) the this keyword will refer to function definition.
While using fat arrow `=>` (ES6 syntax) the this keywords refers to outside function.

```
function fun1() {

   let someVar = 1; 

   someFunctionWithCallback(function() {
      // this keyword referes to function passed to callback
      // cannot access outside variables here
      console.log(someVar) // undefined
   });

   someFunctionWithCallback(() => {
      // this keyword referes to outside function
      console.log(someVar) // will be accessible e.g. 1
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from being more concise code wise.

Arrow functions do not have `arguments` object

Arrow functions do not have their own `this` meaning: if you use this in an arrow function is just like using this outside of it. This is one of the most useful features. why? because with regular functions you end up doing

```
const that = this;
this.service.getUserList().subscribe(function(i : any){
    that.myuserList = i;   
});
```

So to answer you in comments in code:

```
this.service.getuser().subscribe(
i => {
   this.myuserList = i;  // this is the same this above
});

this.service.getUserList().subscribe(function(i : any){
    this.myuserList = i;  // this is not the same this above this line. 
});
```

More on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: fat arrow with args is possible. what do you mean by arrow function do not have args/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731854/why-do-arrow-functions-not-have-the-arguments-array

Answer (score 0):

The actual error in your standard `function` call is that `subscribe` has its own context for this and it is not aware of `myUserList`, thus its undefined in your template context. Previous examples demonstrate assigning `var self = this;` or `var that = this` prior to the call but you could also use a closure or potentially use `bind()` to bind the outer `this` to `subscribe`. However, just use the arrow function unless you're curious.

Simply put, arrow functions preserve the context of `this`, whereas standard functions could have the value of their `this` context changed simply by the caller. Also note that the context of arrow functions can not be changed, for they are lexically scoped. Ergo, .call(), .apply() and .bind() would not work as intended on arrow functions. Remember that functions in JS are Objects, thus why we can call `apply`, `call` or `bind` on a function. Although, callers changing the context of the callee function is typically for some object oriented reason, it does have applications in functional programming as well. Take notice that in the pattern Math.func() is a constructor, meant to be used as a static method vs creating an instance of the Math library like you would an Array, therefore the max() method is not on the prototype. If you were to use .apply() on an Array it would be Array.prototype.map(...).apply(ctx, [values])

> note that because the Math library's `max` function is a constructor context is irrelevant. Unfortunately, `Math.max(..)` does not take an array, ergo **historically** a great way
> to take an array of numbers and pass them into `Math.max(..)` was to use `apply(..`) **without passing context like so**:
>
> ```
>  // es5 way
>  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4],
>      max;
>
> // notice we use apply here to destructure the array  
> // will convert the arguments into a format usable by max
> max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);  // notice context is null
>  
> max => 4
> ```
>
> **In ES6+, you can something like this:**
>
> ```
> const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
>
> // notice how simple this is, just spread the array
> let max = Math.max(...arr);
>
> max => 4
> ```

This is why you would see a lot of code early on that made use of these methods, and while this can seem confusing at first, it is also empowering in many ways. ES6+ fixes much of this with the arrow functions so that `this` operates in a consistent manner. Although, there are still use cases for function expressions, such as you can not define a generator function using arrow functions (yet). I would recommend you checkout [this link](https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread) (javascript.info) resource - it offers amazing explanations of spread, rest, arrow functions, and practically everything else you can imagine.