# Wsy this arrow function doesn't work with 'arguments.length'?

Tags: javascript, arguments, arrow-functions

I'm wondering why the following arrow function, named 'countArg2' doesn't work.
Is there anybody can explain what's wrong please?

---

This works

```
function countArg1() {
    return arguments.length;
}
countArg1(1, 2, 3);   //3
```

This doesn't work..

```
const countArg2 = () => arguments.length;
countArg2(1, 2, 3);
 // VM6745:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731854/why-do-arrow-functions-not-have-the-arguments-array

Comment: Hi Suzuran: It's already answered here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731854/why-do-arrow-functions-not-have-the-arguments-array

Comment: [Arrow function expressions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) -> Differences & Limitations -> _"Does not have `arguments`, or `new.target` keywords."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the arguments to the arrow function like this

```js
const countArg2 = (...arguments) => arguments.length;
console.log(countArg2(1, 2, 3));
 // VM6745:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined
 // at mArgs (<anonymous>:1:29)
 // at <anonymous>:2:1
```