# Getting error in console Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined after upgrading the webpack 4 to webpack 5

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, debouncing, webpack-cli

Getting error in console Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined after upgrading the webpack 4 to webpack 5. This arguments is in debounce funtion

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do arrow functions not have the arguments array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731854/why-do-arrow-functions-not-have-the-arguments-array)

Answer (score 1):

The `debounce` function you have here is an arrow function which doesn't have `arguments`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Which leads to this issue.