# I'm using regular function give me correct output when I convert it to arrow function give me error

Tags: javascript

I'm using regular function  give me correct output when I convert it to arrow function give me error
/////////////////////////working prefect////////////////////

```
function sum() {
    total = 0
    for (i in arguments) {
        total += arguments[i]

    }
    console.log(total);
}
sum(20, 80, 90, 70);
```

**output** = 260

/////////////not working prefect using arrow function/////////////

```
var sum = () => {
    total = 0
    for (i in arguments) {
        total += arguments[i]

    }
    console.log(total);
}
sum(20, 80, 90, 70);
```

**Error**

```
0[object Object]function require(path) {
      return mod.require(path);
    }[object Object]c:
```

Comment: `var sum = (...arguments) => {`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731854/why-do-arrow-functions-not-have-the-arguments-array

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions do not have an arguments binding. However, they have access to the arguments object of the closest non-arrow parent function. Named and rest parameters are heavily relied upon to capture the arguments passed to arrow functions. In most cases, using rest parameters is a good alternative to using arguments.

```
var sum = (...arguments) => {
    total = 0;
    for (i in arguments) {
        total += arguments[i]
    }
    console.log(total);
}
sum(20, 80, 90, 70); // returns 260
```